# In R: Sufficient approach to calculate distance of permuted matrix

Tags: r, matrix, distance

Suppose I have matrix

```
x=matrix(c(1:12),4,3)
```

And I calculate the distance of `x` by `as.matrix(dist(x))`

Then, I permute the rows of `x` as `x1` (`ind=sample(4);x1=x[ind,]`,change the order of rows), and I calculate the distance of  `x1` again by `as.matrix(dist(x1))`.

Is there any sufficient approach to calculate the distance of `x1` without using `as.matrix(dist(x1))`?

**I notice the values in `as.matrix(dist(x1))` are already calculated in `as.matrix(dist(x))` but they are in different positions in matrix.**

Comment: Perhaps, you need to subset `as.matrix(dist(x))` with `[ind, ind]`?

Comment: @alexis_laz. Thank you. Problems solved.